# compiler can't find header file on pre-build stage with target_include_directories

Tags: c++, cmake

Language server (clangd) says he can't find lib.h when I trying to include header in lib_gtests.cpp : #include "lib.h".

But when I compile everything is OK and lib_gtests can find a header file.

I may miss something in CMake or I should use an IDE because they are more "smart" and are able to find these pre-build dependencies

```
project
 |
 |-------> src
 |           |----> main.cpp
 |           |----> lib
 |                   |----> lib.cpp
 |                   |----> lib.h
 |
 |
 |-------> tests
 |           |----> lib
 |                   |----> lib_gtests.cpp
 |                   
 |
 |---->CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(unit_tests

    tests/lib/lib_gtests.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(unit_tests PRIVATE lib)

target_include_directories(unit_tests PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/lib)
```

*sorry for a dumb question, I'm new to C++ and CMake*

*and sorry for my English in advance*

*and could I ask for an advice for sources on CMake (not the official docs, they're scary)*

Answer (score 1):

use an IDE (it'll make all these included directories on compile stage visible for a language server by itself, I guess this is why everything works fine for me)

or, if you really want to use some text editor with a language server (for instance NeoVim, as I do. Actually, it's such a pain in the butt but I like this) use ccls as a language server and tell CMake to create compile_commands.json file and create a link to this file in your project directory.

```
cmake -Bbuild -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=YES

ln -s build/compile_commands .
```